# Selenium(Java,Chrome), не нажимаются две клавиши одновременно (Ctrl+t, Ctrl+n)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Следующий код работает. То есть, происходит действие аналогичное нажатию Ctrl+A.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"a");
```

такой тоже работает:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a"));
```

Но вот такой код ни как не хочет работать (ничего не происходит, просто выполнение заканчивается):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

такой тоже не работает

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"n"));
```

Почему с "a" работает, а с t/n нет? Мне нужно открывать новые вкладки и новые окна. Все различные примеры из интернета перепробовал, работать не хочет.Через джаваскрипт не предлагать

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить так:

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```